# tkinter python function takes 1 argument, given 2

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting this error when I try to run my code:

```
File "./countdown.py", line 36, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
File "./countdown.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.create_buttons(self)
TypeError: create_buttons() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
  """Countdown app - simple timer"""

  def __init__(self, master):
    """initialize frame"""
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    #super(Application, self).__init__(master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_buttons(self)

  def create_buttons(self):
    self.startBttn = Button(app, text = "Start")
    self.startBttn.grid()
    self.stopBttn = Button(app, text = "Stop")
    self.stopBttn.grid()
    self.resetBttn = Button(app, text = "Reset")
    self.resetBttn.grid()


### Main Code ###

# create the root window using Tk - an object of tkinter class
root = tk.Tk()

# modify the prog. window (set size, title, etc.)
root.title("Countdown")
root.geometry("200x100")
#instantiate Application
app = Application(root)
```

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while but haven't been able to apply other people's solutions to my code- any ideas? If I remove the tk. before Frame in the class Application declaration I get an error that says Frame not found. If I use **super(Application, self).__init__(master)** instead of the line above it, I get a type error must be class not class object.

Answer (score 3):

Don't explicitly pass `self` when calling a bound method. Call it like this:

```
self.create_buttons()
```

By calling the method with `self.create_buttons(self)` the function receives *two* arguments: the implicit `self` that is passed when calling a bound method (Python does this automatically), and the explicit `self` that you pass in the method call.

---

There are also some other problems with `create_buttons()` which you can fix with this code:

```
  def create_buttons(self):
    self.startBttn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start")
    self.startBttn.grid()
    self.stopBttn = tk.Button(self, text = "Stop")
    self.stopBttn.grid()
    self.resetBttn = tk.Button(self, text = "Reset")
    self.resetBttn.grid()
```

The changes are that you need to use `tk.Button` to reference the `Button` class, and to pass `self` to `tk.Button` which is a reference to the parent frame. Here `self` is the `Application` instance which is a subclass of `tk.Frame` - hence `self` is a frame.

Finally you need to add a call to `mainloop()`:

```
#instantiate Application
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Regarding the problem with `super`, the tkinter classes are of the "old-style" type and do not support `super()`. Therefore you must call the base class with `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)`.

There is a workaround by using multiple inheritance and including `object` as a base class. If you declare `Application` as :

```
class Application(tk.Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """initialize frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
```

then you can use `super()`, but it's hardly worth the effort.

Comment: And `app.mainloop()` for the window to be drawn and events to be processed.

Comment: @AbhishekBalajiR: ahh, yes that is also required, thanks.

Comment: @potatopie: great! You can accept the answer if you like.